# how to find owner of a process without ps

Tags: linux, nginx

Running nginx alpine image. ps is not installed and do not have permission to install ps using apt-get. I have the pid of process. Is there any way I can find out who the owner of process is ?

In this case, I want to figure out who is running nginx master process.

Comment: If it's actually an alpine based image, I'm surprised that `ps` isn't available. This is part of the core `busybox` binary and would be pretty much impossible to remove.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `ls` to find the process owner in the proc directory

```
ls -ld /proc/816
```

If you have `stat` you can display just the owner with fancy formatting:

```
stat -c '%U' /proc/775
avahi
```

Bonus: print your user name without looking at $USER

```
stat -c '%U' /proc/$$
```

Answer (score 2):

You can find all the information relative to a process in `/proc/YOUR_PROCESS_ID/status` where `YOUR_PROCESS_ID`is the PID of your process.

Therefore, you could get the owner of the process by simply running something like this:

```
cat /proc/YOUR_PROCESS_ID/status | grep "Uid" | cut -f 2 | id -nu
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use **docker top** command to get details about all the processes running inside a docker container

Syntax

```
docker top <container ID or name>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about checking from active processes list?

```
top
```

If looking for specific process name:

```
top | grep nginx
```